# Solving $x^4 - x \leq 0$ and $x^2+x-1\leq 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can anybody help me with these two inequalities? I can’t figure them out

> $$x^4 - x \leq 0 \tag{42}$$
>   $$x^2+x-1\leq 5 \tag{43}$$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM5o3.jpg))

My calculations don’t add up to the result and I just don’t know why.

Comment: would you please write what you tried so far. then we'll help you what you can improve

Comment: I’ve tried with:x^4 - x =< 0   -> x^4 =< x   x^3 =< x/x    x=< root3 of 1

Comment: 43. Hint: use $(x+0.5)^2 = x^2+x+0.25$, then subtract $1.25$ from both sides.    42. $x^{3}(x-1) = x^4-x$ then divide by $x$ on both sides. Use those hints. feel free to ask more. But Leonard Euler would have tried hard  by himself before asking.

Comment: But dividing by x on both sides would mean dividing 0 by   x. Wouldn’t that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, only if x is zero. so we consider for the case $x=0$ and $x \neq 0$, separetly

Comment: Is this a system of inequalities, or are they two different problems?

Comment: They are two different problems

Comment: Then post them as two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got a better answer but this is how I usually think when given a similar problem in Math. This might help

$$x^4-x \le 0$$
$$x(x^3-1) \le 0$$
Now we consider three cases.

CASE ONE:  $x=0$ [we need this because we can't divide by zero to simplify]

Then the equation will be true. Therefore $x=0$ is part of the solution.

CASE TWO:  $x \lt 0$ [we need this because inequalities reverse when multiplying/dividing by negative number]

Then remember dividing/multiplying by a negative number reverses the inequality sign.

$$x^3-1 \ge 0$$
$$x^3 \ge 1$$
Now If any negative real number is cubed, it will be negative. So we do not have solution for this case.

CASE THREE: $x \gt 0$ [This is the last remaining set of numbers we did not consider]

$$x^3 \ge 1$$
The solution for this one is obviously $x \ge 1$

Finally we combine the three cases

$$ 0\le x \le 1$$

Answer (score 5):

$\# 42.$  $$x^4-x \le 0$$  $$x(x^3-1) \le 0$$  $$x(x-1)(x^2+x+1) \le 0$$

For this to equal zero, one of the factors must be zero:

$x=0$ or $x=1$.  As @Bladewood pointed out, the factor $x^2+x+1$ is always positive.

For this to be less than zero, two factors need by positive, and one negative.  Thus either $x<0$ and $(x-1)>0$  (cannot happen!) or $x>0$ and $x-1<0$.  This can be written succintly as $0<x<1$.

Summarizing:

The solution is $0 \le x \le 1.$

Comment: $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$ for all real $x$, so would it suffice to consider $x(x - 1) \le 0$?

Comment: @Bladewood, Yes!  That's true and more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

$\#43.$

$$x^2 + x -6 \le 0$$

$$(x+3)(x-2) \le 0$$

Either (i) one factor is zero, or (ii) the factors have alternate signs (one negative, one positive).

(i) $x \in \{ -3,2 \}$

(ii) $ -3 < x < 2 $

The complete solution is thus:

$$ -3 \le x \le 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I would make it entirely  rest upon the high-school theorem on the sign of a quadratic polynomial:

- $x^2+x-6$ has two real roots since its leading coefficient and its constant term have opposite signs and it takes nonpositive values iff $x$ lies in the interval $I$ of the roots. Calculating these roots (e.g. using the *rational roots theorem*), we obtain the condition
  $$ x\in I=[-3,2].$$
- $x^4-x=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, and the same theorem says $x^2+x+1$ is positive, so $x^4-x$ has the sign of the quadratic polynomial $x(x-1)$, which is nonpositive, again, on the interval
  $J=[0,1]$.